# Is possible sponge vía proxy to a https address?

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I'm working with a virtuoso-opensource cloned from github and compiled on last Friday. The software will be used in a course.

The university proxy resolves any (HTTP or HTTPS) requirement ok.

Any query including a reference to dbpedia (in example), always returns

*Virtuoso 22023 Error RDFXX: The HTTPS retrieval is not supported via proxy*

This is the test query:

```
define get:proxy "proxy.fing.edu.uy:3128"
define get:soft "soft"
SELECT *
FROM  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Uruguay>
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
```

Some idea about how the problem can be resolved?

Thanks
FDO.

Answer (score 0):

Also [asked and answered](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-22023-error-rdfxx-the-https-retrieval-is-not-supported-via-proxy/2719) on [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com) —

> A patch has been [committed](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/385790ab593b73e6c0c849fa5067209eece1139a) to the [open source develop/7 branch](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/develop/7) that should resolve this issue. Thus can you please rebuild with the [commit](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/385790ab593b73e6c0c849fa5067209eece1139a) and try again …

Please confirm whether this patch resolved your issue, on each and every site you posted about it!